# How to see which functions are public and available in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I doing the [MOOC Startup Engineering](https://www.coursera.org/course/startup). It teaches how to use node, but it seems the code is not working anymore. The code is located here:

https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/startup/code/market-research.js

I have downloaded the dependencies as follows:

```
# Install npm dependencies. This will create a node_modules directory in the current working directory. Don't cd into other directories right now; later we'll show how to install modules globally.
npm install restler csv accounting
```

When I execute `node market-research.js`, I got the error:

```
/home/ubuntu/market-research.js:47
    csv()
    ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at csv2console (/home/ubuntu/market-research.js:47:5)
    at Request.response2console (/home/ubuntu/market-research.js:65:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.mixin._fireSuccess (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:226:10)
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:158:20
    at IncomingMessage.parsers.auto (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:394:7)
    at Request.mixin._encode (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:195:29)
    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:154:16
    at Request.mixin._decode (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:170:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:147:14)
```

As the code includes `var csv = require('csv');`, I'm trying to figure out if it is been actually imported.

If I have understood well, somewhere in the *node_modules* must be a `exports.csv= csv;`. **Is there a way to check which variables or functions have been exported?**

I have written `exports`. Node returned: `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

Comment: the csv module that it import has been updated and it no longer compatible doing it `csv()` way. the csv repo is https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv. try to use older version.

Comment: @wayne thanks but why is not working anymore? Or how could I fix it? Finally, is there a way to check which variables or functions have been exported?

Comment: @wayne I think the the csv module has just an actually different API nowadays, right? Anyway, the question "Is there a way to check which variables or functions have been exported?" is still open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it work modify you package.json, change the version number for csv in "dependencies", but I can't remember which version do `csv()`.

to see a list of public functions the easiest way is open a bash/cmd/console whatever terminal you using inside the project folder that has node_modules.

```
node -> hit enter
var csv = require('csv');
csv. -> then hit tab couple of times
```

Comment: When I type:  `var csv = require('csv');`, it returns: _undefined_. Then I type `csv.`, and it returns _..._ No matter how many times I push enter, it returns _..._

Comment: you need to do it inside the project folder that has node_modules where you have npm install csv module.

Comment: I think I did what  you said: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3653993/Clipboard01.png

Comment: is either your terminal or your node version is really low http://pbrd.co/1uh11DS. anyway the csv functions are well documented in the github.

Comment: it is the latest version of cygwin, but I'm managing a Ubuntu instance of Amazon. I wonder if I have to update either the local or the remote instance of the terminal. It seems a different topic though, so I asked that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865139/cygwin-to-connect-an-amazon-ubuntu-14-04-instance-update-the-local-or-remote-te